# Calculate the distribution function of Y in terms of the distribution function of X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let the time until a new car breaks down be denoted by X, and let Y =
>   \begin{cases} 
>       X & x\leq 5 \\
>       5 & x\gt 5
> \end{cases}
>   Then Y is the life of the car, if it lasts less than 5 years, and is 5 if it lasts longer than 5 years. Calculate the distribution function of Y in terms of F, the distribution function of X.

I'm not sure I understand what is happening in this problem. So if the car breaks down after 6 years, then the life of the car is 5 years? And this is not a distribution function, but we need to use this to find the distribution function of Y? I'm very confused and not sure where to take the first step.

Comment: yes, the life of any car that breaks down after over 5 years is simply noted as 5 years. probably for warranty analysis purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $Y=X\wedge 5$, so that for $t\geqslant 0$, 
$$
F_Y(t) := \mathbb P(Y\leqslant t) = F(t)\mathsf 1_{[0,5)}(t) + \mathsf 1_{[5,\infty)}(t).
$$
In other words, $Y$ has the distribution of $X$ on $[0,5)$, and a point mass of magnitude $1-F(5)$ at $t=5$.